# Java: Running cmd commands (multiple commands with multiple arguments at once)

Tags: java, command-line, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

I run cmd (command line) and running my batch file from Java this way:

```
final String cmd = "cmd /c C: && dir && cd C:\MyApp\Maxi && dir && C:\MayApp\Maxi\deploy.bat";

try {


            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

            int ch;

            while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("IOException on CMD executing statement");
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It was working successfully, but I modified the batch file and added some argument, so I have to pass a name to the batch file so i tried this:
(I send "Name1" as argument)

```
final String cmd = "cmd /c C: && dir && cd C:\MyApp\Maxi && dir && C:\MayApp\Maxi\deploy.bat Name1";

try {


            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

            int ch;

            while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("IOException on CMD executing statement");
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But its not working now and the command is not executed. I only get the "dir" command output.

Can anyone help ?

> Note: The commands run successfully on CMD, but its not working from
>   java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want do multiple tasks in one command? e.g. Change to C:\, dir and then execute?

You can easily club all these tasks to one batch file.

That would help you "not" compiling you code again in case some directory structure changes.

Comment: because the directory name is parameterized with a variable in my code, and i need to move the cursor to a specific directory before calling my batch file. Do you think its going to work this way ?

Comment: First, you definitely do not need DIR. Secondly, provide double quotes to you command. e.g.  && "C:\\MayApp\\Maxi\\deploy.bat" "Name1"

Comment: I only use "DIR" to check if the cursor is moving and if there's an output.

And thank you its working now :)

Comment: how do i run commands that are present in a config file through the same java code? I want to run command line scripts through the same java code, I could run it when i hardcoded it but i want to run these commands from a config file, please let know how to do?